# Filter XML for specific element value in C#

Tags: c#, xml

My `xml` document looks like:

```
<Report>
  <id>820</id>
  <number>u_incident_1</number>
  <Entry>
    <findings>1</findings>
    <area>PS</area>
    <section>Section 1</section>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <findings>2</findings>
    <area>PR</area>
    <section>Section 2</section>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
    <image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
  </Entry>
  <RE_image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</RE_image>
  <RE_image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</RE_image>
</Report>
```

The goal is to extract `<image>` elements out of `<Entry>` element, which has `<section>Section 1</section>` element as part of it.

So far I was able to extract all images related to `<image>` element (6 in total), however I find it hard to only return the ones that I need. The code I am using is:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("mypath\Report.xml");
            var reportElement = xmlDocument.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "Report").First();
            var allEntries = reportElement.Elements().Where(xe => xe.Name.LocalName == "Entry").ToList();
            var allImages = allEntries.SelectMany(xe => xe.Elements().Where(xz => xz.Name.LocalName == "image"));

            // to show the image values
            foreach (var x in allImages.Nodes())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
            }
```

How to modify the code to filter images with `<section>Section 1</section>` element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputXMLFile = @"e:\Temp\Sanosi.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputXMLFile);
    
    var images = xdoc.Descendants("Entry")
        .Where(x => x.Element("section").Value.Equals("Section 1"))
        .Elements("image");
        
    Console.WriteLine(images);
}
```

**Output**

```
IEnumerable<XElement>

<image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
<image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
<image>R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==</image>
```

Comment: Perfecto :) works as it supposed to, thanks a lot :)

Comment: This worked fine for quite some time, now I have xml files with huge sizes, and it seems the XDocument cannot handle them. What I read is that xmlReader is the one to use. Would you please show me how to use xmlReader instead of XDocument in the above example ?

Comment: Please create a new question for that.

Comment: please find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032690/filter-large-xml-for-specific-element-value-in-c-sharp-using-xmlreader/68033408#68033408

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication180
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement Entry = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName == "Entry") && ((string)x.Element("findings") == "1")).FirstOrDefault();

            XNamespace ns = Entry.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<string> images = Entry.Elements(ns + "image").Select(x => (string)x).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please let me know how the code will differ if the xml document has a namespace ?