# Filter Large XML for specific element value in C# Using xmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

In this thread:
[Filter XML for specific element value in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034130/filter-xml-for-specific-element-value-in-c-sharp)

I was able to filter `xml` files to look for specific elements using `XDocument`. However, with huge `xml` files, it seems `XDocument` is not a feasible solution as it fails with `System.OutOfMemoryException` message. Digging around, it looks like `xmlReader` is more memory efficient when handling large `xmls`.

How to re-write the accepted answer, to use `xmlReader`, to get the same result?

Comment: Is your xaml with a statical structure? If so you can try with importing it to a c# class

Comment: Yeah, deserialise it, and bam! Filter it how you like.. is that not an option?

Comment: @Emanuele yes the structure is static. Can you please paste a code that does so, using the same xml in the mentioned link above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It is very scalable and can process multi GB size XML files without any problem.

The *XStreamingElement* is using an extension method that streams the source XML filtered by a `<section>Section 1</section>` node using an `XmlReader`.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputXMLFile = @"e:\Temp\Sanosi.xml";
    const string outputXMLFile = @"e:\Temp\Sanosi_Streamed.xml";
    const string ROW = "Entry";
    const string FILTER = "Section 1";

    // Stream XML to file system
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    // Shape output XML
    XStreamingElement newXML = new XStreamingElement("root",
       from element in StreamElements(inputXMLFile, ROW)
            .Where(x => x.Element("section").Value.Equals(FILTER))
       select new XElement(ROW, element.Elements("image")
          ));

    newXML.Save(outputXMLFile, SaveOptions.OmitDuplicateNamespaces);

    FileInfo fileBefore = new FileInfo(inputXMLFile);
    FileInfo fileAfter = new FileInfo(outputXMLFile);

    timer.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Streamed XML file '{0}', {1} bytes to file system as: '{2}', {3} bytes{5}Elapsed time: {4}",
      fileBefore.FullName
      , fileBefore.Length
      , fileAfter.FullName
      , fileAfter.Length
      , timer.Elapsed
      , Environment.NewLine);
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> StreamElements(string fileName, string elementName)
{
    using (var rdr = XmlReader.Create(fileName))
    {
        rdr.MoveToContent();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if ((rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (rdr.Name == elementName))
            {
                var e = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;
                yield return e;
            }
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not solve the Out Of Memory issue.

Comment: @jdweng, I am regularly using this method to process multi GB XML files. The Windows 10 OS Task Manager doesn't show any memory use spikes.

Comment: @jdweng, Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Comment: You are not using a huge file like OP.  XML linq often with huge files get out of memory error.  The only way of solving is using XmlReader like my posted code.  Read the question.  Your machine may have a lot more memory that the OPs.

Comment: @jdweng, just FYI, with that technique I was able to process XML files with the size of 30+ GB on a machine with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: Wouldn't is depend on the amount of data returned?  If OP has a large number of "Entry Element" he would get out of memory.  Most people need to parse entire XML and you are returning only a few tags.

Comment: @jdweng, good question. My method streams from a source XML file into an output XML file. No memory involvement in between.

Comment: Do you get a out of memory error with just XElement.Load(filename)?  If you have swap space enabled the memory with go to your drive. OPs may not be using swap space.

Comment: @jdweng, why is there the dispute about memory consumption or potential out of memory problems if both your answer and this answer in the end rely on `XElement.ReadFrom` in `var e = XElement.ReadFrom(rdr) as XElement;` or `XElement entry = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);`?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Perfect, your code works for me :) What I need extra, is how to embed the namespace in the code, as my original xml has a namespace inside ?

Comment: @khidirsanosi, (1) Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. (2) Please ask a new question to deal with namespaces, and provide samples of both input XML as well as output XML.

Answer (score -1):

I use code like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "Entry")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("Entry");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement entry = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after I get the "entry" xelement in the last if statement, how do I then search this element to check if Section = Section 1, so that I get the element I am looking for ? something like Entry.Descendants().Where(x => x.Element("section").Value.Equals("Section 1")).Elements("image");

Comment: Try following : List<XElement> images = entry.Descendants("image").ToList();