# How to process large xml downloaded from wikitionary

Tags: xml, wiki

I downloaded the file `enwiktionary-20231101-pages-articles.xml` from wiktionary, but unfortunately it seems useless since I cannot open it. The data size is around 8GB. I tried VSCode, the problem is still "cannot open the large XML". I tried this snipped in Java, it was the same problem.

```
  try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse("src/main/resources/enwiktionary-20231101-pages-articles.xml");

            // Access elements and data from the XML
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("page");
            System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
            
//            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
//                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
//                System.out.println(node);
//                break;
//            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I found this link is like a replacement for above file. https://dictionaryapi.dev/, which can saves me a lot of effort in processing XML format.
My current only concern is to get list of words, so I can download them via above link. Do you know how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: It is very easy to stream XML by using C# and **LINQ to XML** in the Net Framework. Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032690/filter-large-xml-for-specific-element-value-in-c-sharp-using-xmlreader/

Comment: *not working* is never a good description of problem. Please relay any errors or undesired results.

Comment: @Parfait the problem is "can't open the large XML file".

Comment: Then, your machine can't parse the whole file in memory at once. As answered, look to streaming the XML file to extract the contentv you need iteratively to avoid holding whole tree in RAM. Many asked and answered questions about this across stacks (Java, Python, etc.) on SO!

Comment: @Parfait : It is not the machine, it is the library.  Most libraries will give out of memory exceptions when opening huge xml files.  Have seen the issue for years.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a streaming technology (one that doesn't build a tree in memory). The usual candidates are Java SAX processing, Python ElementTree, or Streaming XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a powershell script.  Folllowing uses a combination of XmlReader and Xml Linq and then writes results to a csv file.

```
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$uri = 'https://dumps.wikimedia.org/shnwiktionary/20231101/shnwiktionary-20231101-pages-articles.xml.bz2'
$zipPath = 'c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'
$tempFolder = 'c:\temp\'
$Source = 'shnwiktionary-20231101-pages-articles.xml.bz2'
$Target = 'shnwiktionary-20231101-pages-articles.xml'
$csv = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI $uri
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tempFolder + $source, $response.Content)

cd $tempFolder
Set-Alias Start-SevenZip $zipPath
Start-SevenZip x $Source


$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($tempFolder + $Target)
$reader.MoveToContent();
$nsName = $reader.GetAttribute('xmlns');
$namespace = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]::Get($nsName);
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
while($reader.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if ($reader.Name -ne 'page')
   {
      $reader.ReadToFollowing('page')
   }
   if ($reader.EOF -eq $False)
   {
       $page = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
       $title = $page.Element($namespace + 'title').Value
       $ns = $page.Element($namespace + 'ns').Value
       $id = $page.Element($namespace + 'id').Value

       $revision = $page.Element($namespace + 'revision')
       $parentId = $revision.Element($namespace + 'id').Value
       $timestamp = $revision.Element($namespace + 'timestamp').Value

       $contributor = $revision.Element($namespace + 'contributor')
       $username = $contributor.Element($namespace + 'username').Value
       $userId = $contributor.Element($namespace + 'id').Value

       $model = $revision.Element($namespace + 'model').Value
       $format = $revision.Element($namespace + 'format').Value
       $text = $revision.Element($namespace + 'text').Value

       $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
           title = $title
           ns = $ns
           id = $id
           parantId = $ParentId
           timestamp = $timestamp
           username = $username
           userId = $userId
           model = $model
           format = $format
           $text = $text
       }
       $table.Add($newRow) | out-null 
   }
}
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csv -NoTypeInformation
```