# 100 GB XML into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm having issues both because I have no idea what I'm doing, but also because my data file is so damn large.

TLDR: I have downloaded SQL Server 2022 and SQL Server Management Studio and need my huge file imported into a table.

I have this XML which is approx. 100 GB and contains the whole vehicle registry. I need to import this into a table, so I can do lookups, nothing fancier than that. But I can't seem to figure out how to import it. I can't open the file really anywhere other than Microsoft Edge, because of its size.

It also baffles me how I'm supposed to read my file, it doesn't have the root and stuff, just plain text.

[Screenshot of XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sosd8.jpg)

Comment: Filetype: Microsoft Edge HTML Document (.xml) - This is what it says, do you have any idea to what i could be then?

Comment: sql server have a limit to 2gb for "stuff". if you're previewing file in browser, it probably haven't rendered it completely yet. I would suggest using a streaming lib or some sort to shred the xml by bits and just insert the actual data, not the giant xml blob into the database.

Comment: Can you recommend a good streaming lib?

Comment: I helped somebody load an xml file into sql  a number of years ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173567/unstructured-xml-via-non-tab-deliminator/50180324).  I used c# to read the huge xml file.  Today I would do same except use Powershell to read xml and load into database.  Here is example of using Powershell to parse a huge xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77424647/how-to-process-large-xml-downloaded-from-wikitionary/77426156#77426156

Comment: i've used XStream for java, but haven't tried it with 100 gb files. There are probably already answers to that on stackoverflow, but it's a bit out of scope for your question

Comment: @jdweng I may have to add here i never have used either C# or powershell, but when looking at the powershell code i cant seem to figure out how i can choose a local file instead of the URL. i have the 100GB file locally downloaded from an FTP server.

Comment: Best option is probably using something like C# or Python or Powershell to read the XML using a forwards-only reader, and shred it down into separate nodes which you can put into proper tables. SQL Server cannot handle such large XML files. If you post a sample of the XML as text not images, and the tables you want to insert into, we can do something.

Comment: The XDocument parse method in PS will take either a URL or a File.  My code download from a URI and saves the XML to a file.  Then uses the XDocument Parse method to read the file.

Comment: `XDocument.Parse` will load the whole thing into memroy, which is going to fail. You need an `XmlReader` to read forwards through the file.

Comment: @Charlieface i have posted some the first couple of lines, but as you can see, its just plain text

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah im wondering that too.  it says "Filetype: Microsoft Edge HTML Document (.xml)" but the format is all wrong. but i am not sure if its because it cant read the thing when its 100GB

Comment: Where can we read more about your XML file? Could you please refer us to its source on the Web?

Comment: @Charlieface its too big for notepad++, i can only open in microsoft edge. i have found this parser tho: https://github.com/orest-d/esstatistikliste. which is exactly for what im trying to do, now i just need to figure out how to use it :)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky its a FTP server under the vehicle ministry in Denmark "https://motorst.dk/erhverv/motorregistret-for-virksomheder/faa-adgang-til-motorregistret/andre-adgange" in the bottom on where it says "statistikudtræk"

Comment: @Charlieface That actually parses it quite well, not sure what to do with it tho

Comment: @Charlieface : You have to use XmlReader on huge xml files otherwise you get out of memory.  I already provided link to read huge files.

Comment: Made a slight mistake.  My 2nd link is using XmlReader, not XDocument.  XmlReader will read a file using the create method : $reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create(filename)

Comment: @Charlieface i have attached a pic of the powershell :) ty for helping

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, only paste them in as text. We need a valid sample, so it needs the starting and ending tags as well as namespaces. Please also show what you are trying to achieve with it, what SQL tables do you want?

Comment: @Charlieface my bad, but 1 car is approx. 180 lines, is there anywhere i can send it to you. its too long for post here?

Comment: Never used SQL before, so not sure what SQL Tables i want. i just need to be able to look up the vin number called "KoeretoejOplysningStelNummer" in the XML and then be able to receive the data from that car. so a car has to be only 1 row i guess and then just fill as many columns as it needs

Comment: Cut it down to a minimal valid example, just a few nodes, maybe take out some of the attributes or something. Again: what actual data do you want to see? Show a full example in your post, don't just keep commenting

Comment: @Charlieface i put a sample in the post now.
i want to see all of it more or less. this is just for a database, where i can lookup just about everything about a vehicle. for different purposes in the future

Comment: The xml is not valid.  The namespace "ns" is not defined.  The namespace is usually at beginning of the file, so you are missing the beginning.

Comment: @jdweng any easy way to fix it or should i give up on this project?

Comment: @jdweng It is there, just missing space now fixed. But missing end tags. And we still don't know desired results.

Comment: I added missing closing tags so xml is not valid.  What section(s) of the file do you need?  Are there any repeated sections?  You should include at least two copies of any repeats.

Comment: @jdweng the namespace is defined on the first element.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft : That is after the OP updated the xml.

Comment: Talk about using wrong tool for the job, together with the most bloated column names. This file would probably be under 1gb as csv. Although, maybe the real reason is to discourage amateurs from trying to use this data

Comment: @siggemannen : XML has lots of advantages over CSV.  For example XML has a schema check.  XML is also nested so data does not have to be repeated on each row.

Comment: I would start by designing the database tables and fields.  I like using an excel worksheet to help with the design part.  The create manually the table and field of the SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio.  Then once the tables are created you can read the xml and inset the data into the database.

Comment: @jdweng i have found this script which is the exact task made to the exact file. but im not sure how to use it, but it shows the output well: https://github.com/orest-d/esstatistikliste/

Comment: @Charlieface  i have found this script which is the exact task made to the exact file. but im not sure how to use it, but it shows the output well: https://github.com/orest-d/esstatistikliste/

Comment: I can easily import the xml file using power shell.  You have to design the database.  All the python does is reads the file.  It doesn't use it the way you need it.  I said you first need to design the database.  Once you determine the table and fields of the database the rest is simple.

Comment: @jdweng i have made one in the post, is that good enough you think?

Comment: Look good except SQL Server does not have a BOOLEAN type.  Use Bit instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a portion of the PS script to parse the xml

```
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$server = '.\sqlexpress'
$database = 'ESStatistik'
$connString = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=True"

$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($filename)
$reader.MoveToContent();
$nsName = $reader.GetAttribute('xmlns:ns');
$ns = [System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace]::Get($nsName);

$id = 1

while($reader.EOF -eq $False)
{
   if ($reader.Name -ne 'Statistik')
   {
      $reader.ReadToFollowing('Statistik', $nsName)
   }
   if ($reader.EOF -eq $False)
   {
       $statistik = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($reader)
       $KoeretoejIdent = [System.Numerics.BigInteger]::Parse($statistik.Element($ns + 'KoeretoejIdent').Value)
       $KoeretoejArtNummer = [int]::Parse($statistik.Element($ns + 'KoeretoejArtNummer').Value)
       
       $RegistreringNummerNummer = $statistik.Descendants($ns + 'KoeretoejAnvendelseNummer')[0].Value
       $KoeretoejOplysningStatus = $statistik.Descendants($ns + 'KoeretoejOplysningStatus')[0].Value

       $query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Statistik (StatistikID, KoeretoejIdent,KoeretoejArtNummer,RegistreringNummerNummer,KoeretoejOplysningStatus) VALUES ($id, $KoeretoejIdent, $KoeretoejArtNummer, $RegistreringNummerNummer,`'$KoeretoejOplysningStatus`')";
       Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $connString -Query $query

       $id += 1
       
   }
}
```