# PHP when validating a large XML file with an xsd, the script just dies

Tags: php, xml, xsd

With just 1000 entries it works but more than 100 000 it just dies.

this is my code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;


libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->load($xmlFile);
libxml_clear_errors();


if ($dom->schemaValidate($xsdFile)) {
    echo 'Validation successful. The XML file is valid against the schema.'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'Validation failed. Errors:'.PHP_EOL;
    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "\n" . $error->message . PHP_EOL;
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

Comment: check the logs for errors.. probably out of memory

Comment: What can i do to avoid that

Comment: Increase the memory limit... if it was that

Comment: Maybe you are getting an exception.

Comment: I believe that libxml2 is able to do schema validation in streaming mode, though I can't help with the details of PHP invocation. Alternatively, use SaxonC-EE (my company's product).

Comment: May be useful: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/php-way-to-do-xsd-validation-of-an-xml-stream-in-php/. see: You may use XMLReader.  It is documented in the manual.

Comment: I tried the site that Ryan Vincent sent, it doesn't kill the execution but it doesn't show if there is an error in the xml file

Comment: I file is huge than you have to use XmlReader.  See following Powershell solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437032/100-gb-xml-into-sql-server-database/77460889#77460889